# How to refer to column headers as if they were lowercase, but not actually change them

Tags: python, pandas

The .csv and .xlsx reports I am working with are inconsistent with capital letters in the headers.

I want to refer to the column header names with all lowercase, and also want the script to see the headers as if they are lowercase, but I DON'T want to actually change the headers - I need to preserve their current capitalization so that they export back to a .csv or .xlsx the same as they imported.

Below is obviously not correct and is a simplified example, but it is what I am attempting to achieve - specifically this:  `str.lower((df['name'])`

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Name':['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack'],
        'Age':[20, 21, 19, 18],
        'Weight':[20, 210, 190, 180]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.loc[str.lower((df['name']).str.lower().isin(['tom', 'jack']))
    , 'Weight'] = df['Weight'] * df['Age']

print(df)
```

Comment: If you don't want to change the original header, why not work on a copy of the original dataframe? then you can change it and work with the copy.

Comment: `df[df.columns[df.columns.str.lower() == 'name']]`

Comment: why don't you just save the original headers to a variable, work with their lowercased version, and then, just before exporting the DataFrame, set the headers to the original ones? (mawo's solution)

Answer (score 1):

Is it an option to simply rename the columns and undo the change before writing back?

```
In [7]: column_names = dict(zip(df.columns.str.lower(), df.columns))

In [8]: column_names
Out[8]: {'name': 'Name', 'age': 'Age', 'weight': 'Weight'}

In [9]: df.columns = df.columns.str.lower()

In [10]: df
Out[10]: 
    name  age  weight
0    Tom   20      20
1   nick   21     210
2  krish   19     190
3   jack   18     180

In [11]: df.rename(columns=column_names).to_csv(....)
Out[11]: 
    Name  Age  Weight
0    Tom   20      20
1   nick   21     210
2  krish   19     190
3   jack   18     180
```

Doing this inplace all the time seems like a massive hassle.

Comment: You could also just store the old columns `og_cols = df.columns` then you wouldn't need to go through all the map and replace logic. Just do `df.columns = og_cols` when you're done.

Comment: I posted an answer using a mapping table, but this is much more pragmatic. I'd just add you could have a df loader function which encapsulates this logic in one place, and a df store function which reverses the names. Somewhat beyond the scope of the question, if you have full control of the sheets, maybe time to add consistency to them? Cleaner data structures is always better than adding algorithmic complexity.

Comment: @HenryEcker Storing the old columns will no longer work if you manipulate the dataframe and delete columns or create new ones. The approach with `replace` covers these scenarios. If that is not a requirement, I fully agree.